# Internal compiler error on a template function specialization

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2017, internal-compiler-error

I have a code that worked on Lunix/GCC. However, when compiling on Windows/MSVC 2017, I am facing an `internal compiler error`:

**.hpp:**

```
namespace g2o {
namespace internal {

    template<typename MatrixType>
    inline void axpy(const MatrixType& A, const Eigen::Map<const Eigen::VectorXd>& x, int xoff, Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd>& y, int yoff) {
        y.segment<MatrixType::RowsAtCompileTime>(yoff) += A * x.segment<MatrixType::ColsAtCompileTime>(xoff);
    }

    template<int t>
    inline void axpy(const Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, t>& A, const Eigen::Map<const Eigen::VectorXd>& x, int xoff, Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd>& y, int yoff) {
        y.segment(yoff, A.rows()) += A * x.segment<Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, t>::ColsAtCompileTime>(xoff);
    }

    template<> /*******ERROR HERE*******/
    inline void axpy(const Eigen::MatrixXd& A, const Eigen::Map<const Eigen::VectorXd>& x, int xoff, Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd>& y, int yoff) {
        y.segment(yoff, A.rows()) += A * x.segment(xoff, A.cols());
    }   
} // end namespace internal
} // end namespace g2o
```

I saw solution telling that I should do the following:

```
template<Eigen::MatrixXd> inline void axpy<Eigen::MatrixXd> ....
```

However, it did not work.

---

Error message as it was produced by the compiler:

> Error C1001   An internal error has occurred in the compiler.

Comment: The error really doesn't say anything more?

Comment: @usr2564301 yes, it does not

Comment: @KenWhite OK, I edited

Comment: Post a complete program that crashes the compiler, and we can look into it.

Comment: MSVC 2017 has been updated a lot recently. It would be best to include the complete version number in the question.

Comment: Independent of compiler, I would have written that as an overload and not a specialization in the first place: get rid of the `template <>`.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with MSVC++, it doesn't handle long inputs as well as other compilers. It likes compact compilation units and PCH (Pre-Compiled Headers). Because templates are always header-only, they usually cause lots or recursive #include directives and long compilation unit as a result. MSVC++ sometimes can't handle that and cause an Internal Compiler error. IMHO this is your case. Decoupling code to few compilation units, extensive use of forward declarations and Pimpls and moving #include directives from *.hpp to *.cpp usually worked for me.